# What if all the attributes are permitted in the params.require(:obj)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Assume the params are like this:

```
params: { obj: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } }
```

If the attribute c is not permitted:

```
params.require(:obj).permit(:a, :b)
```

However, if the obj is required and all of the attributes in it are permitted, is it necessary to add each attribute specifically  in the "permit()"?

```
params.require(:obj)
```

This will raise a ForbiddenAttributesError.

Comment: yes you need to specify all of them... otherwise it assumes that none of them are permitted. `require(:obj)` just tells it that you require `:obj` to be a key int he params-hash... not that "anything under obj is ok"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `permit!`

```
params.require(:obj).permit!
```

[`permit!`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values) allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Strong Parameters and all about accessing the attributes via the controller and by the User end.

The permitted attribuites are those which will be editable and operationable by the end user, Attributes which are not assigned into that , Will not get update with the database.

You can use permit! for all the attributes, But make sure you are required to give all the params accessible by the end user.

```
params.require(:obj).permit!
```

`permit!` allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.